# How to print the constructors of a type in GHCi?

Tags: haskell, ghci, haskell-mode

Using `:t` I can print the type of an expression. But how do I see the constructors of that type? Also is there a shortcut for this in Haskell mode for emacs?

This seems like a basic thing, but I can't find it. Maybe I'm just searching the wrong terms...

In general, what is the easiest way to see the print the definition of a type without having to go to the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:info`, or just `:i`, is what you want:

```
>>> :i Either
data Either a b = Left a | Right b  -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
... plus all of Either's instances
```

From the [GHCi documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.10.3/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-commands.html):

> :info *name* ...
>
> Displays information about the given name(s). For example, if *name* is
>   a class, then the class methods and their types will be printed; if
>   *name* is a type constructor, then its definition will be printed; if
>   *name* is a function, then its type will be printed. If *name* has been
>   loaded from a source file, then GHCi will also display the location of
>   its definition in the source.

Haskell-mode in Emacs has `haskell-process-do-info` ([source](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/blob/master/haskell-commands.el#L311)), for which one [Haskell on Emacs Tutorial](https://github.com/serras/emacs-haskell-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial.md) recommends setting the keybinding `C-c C-n C-i`.

```
(defun haskell-process-do-info (&optional prompt-value) 
  "Print info on the identifier at point.
If PROMPT-VALUE is non-nil, request identifier via mini-buffer."
...
)
```